# Как отображать штрихкоды в матричной структуре?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, itext

Как отображать разные штрихкоды в нескольких столбцах на одной PDF-странице, используя iText? Допустим, нужно отобразить 12 штрихкодов в трех столбцах на одной PDF-странице. Каждый столбец будет содержать по 4 штрихкода (получается матрица 4 на 3).

Answer (score 0):

Мы создали пример [Barcodes](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/samples/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/tables/Barcodes.java), в котором рассматривается этот вопрос. Ознакомьтесь с получившимся PDF-файлом: [barcodes_table.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/blob/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_barcode_table.pdf)

Здесь нет ничего сложного. Нужно создать таблицу с 4 столбцами и добавить 12 ячеек.

```
Table table = new Table(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    table.addCell(createBarcode(String.format("%08d", i), pdfDoc));
}
```

Метод `createBarcode()` создает ячейку со штрихкодом:

```
public static Cell createBarcode(String code, PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
    BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN(pdfDoc);
    barcode.setCodeType(BarcodeEAN.EAN8);
    barcode.setCode(code);
    Cell cell = new Cell()
            .add(new Image(barcode.createFormXObject(null, null, pdfDoc)))
            .setPaddingTop(10)
            .setPaddingRight(10)
            .setPaddingBottom(10)
            .setPaddingLeft(10);
    return cell;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в iText 7 используются не `PdfPTable` и `PdfPCell`, а `Table` и `Cell`.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы оборачиваете неДжаваСкрипт код в блок ДжаваСкрипт кода. Сейчас исправлю - учтите на будущее )